# Dictionary and Input: How to use the user input in the value

Tags: python, dictionary, input, chatbot

I am working on a kind of chatbot. I am wondering if there is a way to use the `input` as a `value` in the dictionary. For example: when the input is "my name is x" I want to get the answer "Hello x".
I tried this: `"my name is (.*)": ["Hello ! % 1"]` and it didn't worked well. I suppose, I need to define (.*) and %1 but I don't know how to make it.

Please help me if you know a way to make this. Thank you.

```
words = {"good night": ["nighty night", "good night", "sleep well"],
         "good morning": ["good morning", "wakey-wakey!", "rise and shine!"],
         "hi": ["hello", "hey", "hi"],
         "how are you": ["I am good, thank you", "Pretty good,thank you", "Very well, thanks",
                         "I am doing great thanks", "Better than some, not as good as others",
                         "I am better now, it is good to talk to you"],
         "bye": ["see you later", "bye", "bye-bye", "see you soon", "bye for now", "catch you later"],
         "my name is (.*)": ["Hello ! % 1"]
         }

text_punk = input("text something: ")

greet_words = words.keys() #check if the key words is in input_text.
word_available = [word for word in greet_words if word in text_punk]

if word_available: # if words are available take the first of key.
    punk = random.choice(words[word_available[0]])
    print(punk)
    talk(punk) #this is for pyttsx3
else:
    print("problem!")
```

Comment: Is that normal that when inputting `good` you can't either get answer for good night or for good morning ?

Comment: Try using regex to match the key like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21025121/17706960

Comment: @azro well, I think it is ? You should type the whole key to get the value shouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were going for something like this:

```
from random import choice
from re import match, sub

text_punk = ''

while 'bye' not in text_punk:
    words = {"good night": ["nighty night", "good night", "sleep well"],
             "good morning": ["good morning", "wakey-wakey!", "rise and shine!"],
             "hi": ["hello", "hey", "hi"],
             "how are you": ["I am good, thank you", "Pretty good,thank you", "Very well, thanks",
                             "I am doing great thanks", "Better than some, not as good as others",
                             "I am better now, it is good to talk to you"],
             "bye": ["see you later", "bye", "bye-bye", "see you soon", "bye for now", "catch you later"],
             "my name is (.*)": ["Hello ! {1}"]
             }

    text_punk = input("text something: ").lower()

    response = 'I did not get that, sorry'

    for expression in words:
        if m := match(expression, text_punk):
            response = choice(words[expression]).format(*(m.group(i) for i in range(len(m.groups())+1)))
            break

    print(response)
```

Running it with some input:

```
text something: hi
hello
text something: my name is grismar
Hello ! grismar
text something: bye!
catch you later
```

Of course, this is where the magic happens:

```
choice(words[expression]).format(*(m.group(i) for i in range(len(m.groups())+1)))
```

If `expression` matched on the input in `text_punk`, it selects a random phrase from that dictionary value. It then tries to format that chosen value (replacing values in `{}`) with the match group.

It does that by listing all the groups, 0 through however many there are using `range(len(m.groups())+1)`.

For example, if the input is `'my name is grismar'`, group `0` will be `'my name is grismar'` and group `1` will be `grismar`. So the command comes down to:

```
choice(words['my name is (.*)']).format('my name is grismar', 'grismar')
```

And since `choice(words['my name is (.*)'])` can only be `'Hello ! {1}'`, it's really:

```
'Hello ! {1}'.format('my name is grismar', 'grismar')
```

It will also work for multiple greetings:

```py
"my name is (.*)": ["Hello {1}!", "Hey {1}, long time no see!"]
```

And you can have multiple matches:

```py
"my name is ([^\s]+) (.*)": ["Hello {1}!", "Greetings, {2}!", "Mx {2}, first name {1}, OK"]
```

Example:

```
text something: my name is jaap van der velde
Hello jaap!
text something: my name is jaap van der velde
Greetings, van der velde!
text something: my name is jaap van der velde
Mx van der velde, first name jaap, OK
text something:
```

Comment: omg thank you @Grismar for your time and detailed answer, you are the best! I am really appreciated

Comment: You're welcome, you were pretty close already - have a good look at the documentation of `.format()` to understand why and how this works. You can use it to make it even more clever by using named regex matches and named replacements in `.format()`, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Hi @Grismar, I am still working on the same code. I have a question, I will be grateful if you can help me.. So, is it possible to make a kind of reflections? I want get an answer even if the answer is ***I'm*** instead of ***I am...***. when the user input is I am happy I get the answer but when it is I'm happy there is no answer... Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: The simplest way would be to include both answers separately of course, but you could use a regex like `"(?:I'm|I am) happy" : "Glad to hear it."`? But you will run into limitations of the approach you chose at some point - if you need the bot to remember more about what was said for example, you'll need to do more than just match expressions and pick random answers. But that goes way beyond your original question. (note that the `?:` is only in there for a non-matching group, you could leave it out)

Comment: I think it is better and easier to include all of them seperately for now... I'm a high school teacher and trying to build a chatbot for my students to encourage them to speak English... I'm new to python, I created a GUI and for the chatbot, included speech recognition and pyttsx3 to it.. that would be great if the bot could remember the input but I think it is over my head.. I am really grateful for your answer, thanks for leaving your time for me @Grismar. I will just add the contractions.